# Can't find a proper right-curved, non-continuous function

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: plots to reproduce]

Hi everyone! I should reproduce these plots (above) and I'm so far that I have everything except for the plots themselves. Does anyone here have an idea what kind of plots should I take? I'm not a math-pro and google couldn't help me either.

Here the code and what I've got so far (this is my first question and I don't know why the formatting of the code doesn't work, sorry for that):

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        restrict y to domain=-5:5,
        samples=1000,
        ticks=none,
        xmin = -1, xmax = 5,
        ymin = -1, ymax = 5,
        unbounded coords=jump,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        x label style={
          at={(axis cs:5.02,0)},
          anchor=west,
        },
        every axis y label/.style={
          at={(axis cs:0,5.02)},
          anchor=south
        },
        legend style={
          at={(axis cs:-5.2,5)},
          anchor=west, font=\scriptsize
        }
        ]

    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,2);
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:0,2) -- (axis cs:2,2);
    \node[below right, font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:2,0) {$a$};
    \node[below right, font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:2,4) {$stetig$};
    \node[above left, font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:0,2) {$f(a)$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        restrict y to domain=-5:5,
        samples=1000,
        ticks=none,
        xmin = -1, xmax = 5,
        ymin = -1, ymax = 5,
        unbounded coords=jump,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        x label style={
          at={(axis cs:5.02,0)},
          anchor=west,
        },
        every axis y label/.style={
          at={(axis cs:0,5.02)},
          anchor=south
        },
        legend style={
          at={(axis cs:-5.2,5)},
          anchor=west, font=\scriptsize
        }
        ]

    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,2);
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:2,1);
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:0,2) -- (axis cs:2,2);
    \node[below right, font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:2,0) {$a$};
    \node[below right, font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:2,4) {$nicht \; stetig$};
    \node[above left, font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:0,2) {$f(a)$};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems more math than LaTeX/PgfPlots question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the drawing is about continuity and discontinuity, there's no need to exactly plot specifically these functions. You could use any continuous and discontinuous functions. You could even make a coordinates plot with smooth path between.

But let's find a function based on your coordinates. The drawing looks like made of pieces of a circle, so let's use a function which can give us a circle, and limit its domain.

First plot:

```
\addplot [no markers, domain=1.3:4] { sqrt(8-(x-4)^2)};
```

For the second plot, we plot the function two times, but shift it the second time, again with limited domains.

```
\addplot [no markers, domain=1.3:2] { -sqrt(8-(x)^2)+3};
\addplot [no markers, domain=2:2.8] { -sqrt(8-(x)^2)+4};
```

We get:

[image: Function plots]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted. Special thanks to the good explanation!